# How can I update the new random value in Java?

Tags: java, random, while-loop

I just started to learn Java, so my program is made with the most basic codes, and I am having some problems with random numbers. I am suppose to make a program that generates a winning number, then the program itself will try to guess it. And based on the guess is high or low, the program's next guess will be limited in a new range, until it guessed the winning number, just like how humans try to guess the number. However, in the `while` loop, the random number `guess` does not update to a new random number based on the new range, and java keeps looping with the same number over and over again infinitely. At first I thought it is because I do not `return` the new `guess` value, but `return` will stop the `while` loop. I am confused, and I am trying to get some help, thank you very much!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessNum {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int range;
        range = 0;

        int upper;
        upper = 100;

        int lower;
        lower = 0;

        int finaltotal;
        finaltotal = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            int total;
            total = 0;

            int win = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

            int guess = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

            while(guess != win) {

                if(guess > win) {

                    String strGuess;
                    strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                    System.out.println(strGuess);

                    System.out.println("Guess is high!");

                    upper = guess;

                    range = upper - lower + 1;

                    guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                    total += 1;

                }

                if(guess < win) {

                    String strGuess;
                    strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                    System.out.println(strGuess);

                    System.out.println("Guess is low!");

                    lower = guess;

                    range = upper - lower + 1;

                    guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                    total += 1;

                }

            }

            String strGuess;
            strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
            System.out.println(strGuess);

            System.out.println("You win!");

            total += 1;

            finaltotal += total;

        }

        int average = finaltotal / 1000;

        String strAverage;
        strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
        System.out.println(strAverage);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at where you are setting your variables

```
   int range;
    range = 0;

    int upper;
    upper = 100;

    int lower;
    lower = 0;
```

These are outside your loop so when you update them on the first round of guessing they never get reset back to their original values which makes them un-guessable eventually as the new random number could be outside your range. You need to put them inside your counted loop or reset them back to their original values inside the counted loop but outside the while loop.

edit: this probably wasn't clear. you need to reset your upper back to 100, and lower back to 0 after the while loop or before it.

Comment: Yes, but upper and lowest are never reset back to 0 and 100.

Comment: I just checked my code, it is still doing the infinite loop. I let the program to print the new "guess" every time it randomized, and it comes out it is always the same. Which means my Math.random() is not working properly, it is always the same number, and this caused my program to loop forever. How can I solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: try putting `upper = 100;` and `lower = 0;` between your counted loop and your while loop and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i remove your while and move logic to if

TEST 10 times

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

if(guess != win && guess > win) {}
if(guess != win && guess < win) {}
```

CONSOLE:

```
i-->0
win-->70
guess-->59
Your guess is: 59
Your guess is: 78
You win!
i-->1
win-->72
guess-->66
Your guess is: 66
Your guess is: 83
You win!
i-->2
win-->65
guess-->31
Your guess is: 31
Your guess is: 95
You win!
i-->3
win-->60
guess-->90
Your guess is: 90
Your guess is: 38
Your guess is: 68
You win!
i-->4
win-->41
guess-->33
Your guess is: 33
Your guess is: 77
You win!
i-->5
win-->68
guess-->23
Your guess is: 23
Your guess is: 61
You win!
i-->6
win-->50
guess-->47
Your guess is: 47
Your guess is: 48
You win!
i-->7
win-->1
guess-->82
Your guess is: 82
Your guess is: 64
You win!
i-->8
win-->97
guess-->45
Your guess is: 45
Your guess is: 63
You win!
i-->9
win-->82
guess-->80
Your guess is: 80
Your guess is: 80
You win!
The average number of guesses is: 0
```

source code

```
public class ttt {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

            int range;
            range = 0;

            int upper;
            upper = 100;

            int lower;
            lower = 0;

            int finaltotal;
            finaltotal = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                System.out.println("i-->"+i);

                int total;
                total = 0;

                int win = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                int guess = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

                System.out.println("win-->"+win);
                System.out.println("guess-->"+guess);

                    if(guess != win && guess > win) {

                        String strGuess;
                        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                        System.out.println(strGuess);

                        //System.out.println("Guess is high!");

                        upper = guess;

                        range = upper - lower + 1;

                        guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                        total += 1;

                    }

                    if(guess != win && guess < win) {

                        String strGuess;
                        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                        System.out.println(strGuess);

                        //System.out.println("Guess is low!");

                        lower = guess;

                        range = upper - lower + 1;

                        guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                        total += 1;

                    }


                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);

                System.out.println("You win!");

                total += 1;

                finaltotal += total;

            }

            int average = finaltotal / 1000;

            String strAverage;
            strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
            System.out.println(strAverage);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to remove the for loop because the range of maximum and minimum values changes after each loop. When the win value is out of the range, the maximum value is close to the minimum value until the maximum value is equal to the minimum value. Then it will loop the same guss value infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and suggested that you remove the for loop because the maximum and minimum ranges change after each loop. When the win value is out of the range, the maximum value is close to the minimum value until the maximum value is equal to the minimum value. Then it will loop the same guss value infinitely.

```
public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int upper = 100;
    int lower = 0;
    int finaltotal = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int win = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    int guess = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    while (guess != win) {
        if (guess > win) {
            String strGuess;
            strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
            System.out.println(strGuess);
            System.out.println("Guess is high!");
            upper = guess;
            guess = (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower);
            total += 1;
        } else if (guess < win) {
            String strGuess;
            strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
            System.out.println(strGuess);
            System.out.println("Guess is low!");
            lower = guess;
            guess = (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower);
            total += 1;
        }
        String strGuess;
        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
        System.out.println(strGuess);
        System.out.println("You win!");
        total += 1;
        finaltotal += total;
    }
    int average = finaltotal / 1000;
    String strAverage;
    strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
    System.out.println(strAverage);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I changed it for reference

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int finaltotal = 0;
            int total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                int upper = 100;
                int lower = 0;
                int win = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                int guess = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
                while (guess != win) {
                    if (guess > win) {
                        String strGuess;
                        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                        System.out.println(strGuess);
                        System.out.println("Guess is high!");
                        upper = guess;
                        guess = (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower);
                        total += 1;
                    } else if (guess < win) {
                        String strGuess;
                        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                        System.out.println(strGuess);
                        System.out.println("Guess is low!");
                        lower = guess;
                        guess = (int) (Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower);
                        total += 1;
                    }
                }
                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);
                System.out.println("You win!");
                total += 1;
                finaltotal += total;
            }

        int average = finaltotal / 1000;
        String strAverage;
        strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
        System.out.println(strAverage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your for loop at the start was causing the program to do its infinite looping.

import java.util.Random;

public class GuessNum {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int range;
    range = 0;

    int upper;
    upper = 100;

    int lower;
    lower = 0;

    int finaltotal;
    finaltotal = 0;

        int total;
        total = 0;

        int win = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        int guess = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        while(guess != win) {

            if(guess > win) {

                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);

                System.out.println("Guess is high!");

                upper = guess;

                range = upper - lower + 1;

                guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                total += 1;

            } else if(guess < win) {

                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);

                System.out.println("Guess is low!");

                lower = guess;

                range = upper - lower + 1;

                guess = (int)((Math.random() * range) + lower);

                total += 1;

            } else {
                guess = win;
            }

        }

        String strGuess;
        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
        System.out.println(strGuess);

        System.out.println("You win!");

        total += 1;

        finaltotal += total;

    int average = finaltotal / 1000;
    String strAverage;
    strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
    System.out.println(strAverage);
}
```

}

Comment: I just checked my code, it is still doing the infinite loop. I let the program to print the new "guess" every time it randomized, and it comes out it is always the same. Which means my Math.random() is not working properly, it is always the same number, and this caused my program to loop forever. How can I solve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessNum {  

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int range;
    range = 0;

    int upper;
    upper = 100;

    int lower;
    lower = 0;

    int finaltotal;
    finaltotal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        int total;
        total = 0;

        int win = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        int guess = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

        while(guess != win) {

            if(guess > win) {

                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);

                System.out.println("Guess is high!");

                upper = guess;

                range = upper - lower + 1;

                guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                total += 1;
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }

            if(guess < win) {

                String strGuess;
                strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
                System.out.println(strGuess);

                System.out.println("Guess is low!");

                lower = guess;

                range = upper - lower + 1;

                guess = (int)(Math.random() * range + lower);

                total += 1;
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }

        }

        String strGuess;
        strGuess = "Your guess is: " + String.valueOf(guess);
        System.out.println(strGuess);

        System.out.println("You win!");

        total += 1;

        finaltotal += total;

    }

    int average = finaltotal / 1000;

    String strAverage;
    strAverage = "The average number of guesses is: " + String.valueOf(average);
    System.out.println(strAverage);

}
}
```

I took your original code and updated

Comment: I just checked my code, it is still doing the infinite loop. I let the program to print the new "guess" every time it randomized, and it comes out it is always the same. Which means my Math.random() is not working properly, it is always the same number, and this caused my program to loop forever. How can I solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: @ZhongqianChen I think I got this, You need to add Thread.sleep(1000L); at the end of each if. I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: @ZhongqianChen Did u try ?